# How can I put reference field in SimpleList in admin-on-rest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, admin-on-rest

In my project I need to show one reference field in `<SimpleList>` component.
In `<Datagrid>` I can do it:

```
<ReferenceField 
    label="user" 
    source="user_id" 
    reference="User" 
    linkType={false}
>
    <TextField source="first_name" sortable={true} />
</ReferenceField>
```

How can I do the same in SimpleList?

```
small={
      <SimpleList
        primaryText={record => record.number}
        //(I want make reference here with User table
        secondaryText={record => record.user_id }
      />
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this in the meantime?

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek no, I created my own component on base of standard datagrid

Answer (score 5):

Although it seems to be kind of a hack, this is possible when you specify the basePath prop in the reference field:

```
<simpleList 
    secondaryText= { record => 
      (
        <ReferenceField basePath="User" record={record} label="user" source="user_id" reference="User" linkType={false}>
            <TextField source="first_name" />
        </ReferenceField>
      )
    }
/>
```

I found this on [github](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/530) and it worked for me, but it's not really specified in the documentation.